# Шифр Цезаря C++

Tags: c++, шифрование

При заходе в  if (int(cstr[i]) >= 88) происходит замена последовательностью букв. В чем ошибка?

```
void Casesar(string str, int n) {
char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
int *a = new int[str.length() + 1];

char m[] = { 'A',   'B','C','D','E',    'F',    'G',    'H',    'I',    'J',
    'K',    'L',    'M',    'N' ,'O'    ,'P'    ,'Q'    ,'R'    ,'S'    ,'T'    ,'U'    ,'V'    ,'W'    ,'X'    ,'Y'    ,'Z' };

strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (int(cstr[i]) == 32)
        continue;
    if (65 >= int(cstr[i]) <= 87) {
        a[i] = int(cstr[i]);
        a[i] += n;
    }
    if (int(cstr[i]) >= 88) {
        a[i] = int(m[i]) + n - 1;
    }
    cstr[i] = char(a[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    cout << cstr[i];
}

delete[] cstr;
delete[] a; }

int main() {
string str;
int n = 0;
cout << "Enter string: ";
getline(cin, str);

cout << "Key: ";
cin >> n;

Casesar(str, n);

_getch();
return 0; }
```

Comment: А в чём проявляется ошибка? Можно на примере при каких входных данных что получаем и что должны получить?

Comment: А что такое 88? Может, там надо 42 написать было?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что после замены последней буквы алфавита, все остальные не заменяются. Вот пример:

Enter string: Zane
Key: 3
CDEF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделанный метод Цезаря

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

void CaesarIn(int k) {
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("caesarin.txt");

    char buff;
    int iter;

    if (!input.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    else {
        while (!input.eof()) {
            buff = input.get();
            if (buff == ' ')
                output << ' ';
            if (buff == '\n')
                output << '\n';

            if (buff >= 'A' && buff <= 'Z') {
                buff += (k % 26);
                if (buff > 'Z')
                    buff -= 26;
                output << buff;
            }
            if (buff >= 'a' && buff <= 'z') {
                buff += (k % 26);
                if (buff > 'z')
                    buff -= 26;
                output << buff;

            }
            if (buff >= 'А' && buff <= 'Я') {
                buff += (k % 33);
                if (buff > 'Я')
                    buff -= 33;
                output << buff;
            }
            if (buff >= 'а' && buff <= 'я') {
                buff += (k % 33);
                if (buff > 'я')
                    buff -= 33;
                output << buff;
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}

void CaesarOut(int k) {
    ifstream input("caesarin.txt");
    ofstream output("caesarout.txt");

    char buff;
    int iter;

    if (!input.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    else {
        while (!input.eof()) {
            buff = input.get();
            if (buff == ' ')
                output << ' ';
            if (buff == '\n')
                output << '\n';

            if (buff >= 'A' && buff <= 'Z') {
                buff -= (k % 26);
                if (buff > 'Z')
                    buff += 26;
                output << buff;
            }
            if (buff >= 'a' && buff <= 'z') {
                buff -= (k % 26);
                if (buff > 'z')
                    buff += 26;
                output << buff;

            }
            if (buff >= 'А' && buff <= 'Я') {
                buff -= (k % 33);
                if (buff > 'Я')
                    buff += 33;
                output << buff;
            }
            if (buff >= 'а' && buff <= 'я') {
                buff -= (k % 33);
                if (buff > 'я')
                    buff += 33;
                output << buff;
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}

void MonoAlphabetIn(int k)
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("monoalp.txt");

    char buff;
    int iter;

    if (!input.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    else {
        while (!input.eof()) {
            buff = input.get();
            if (buff == ' ')
                output << ' ';
            if (buff == '\n')
                output << '\n';
            if (buff >= 'A' && buff <= 'Z') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('A');
                iter = (iter + k) % 26;
                iter += (int)'A';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'a' && buff <= 'z') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('a');
                iter = (iter + k) % 26;
                iter += (int)'a';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'А' && buff <= 'Я') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('А');
                iter = (iter + k) % 32;
                iter += (int)'А';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'а' && buff <= 'я') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('а');
                iter = (iter + k) % 32;
                iter += (int)'а';
                output << char(iter);
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}

void MonoAlphabetOut(int k)
{
    ifstream input("monoalp.txt");
    ofstream output("monoalpout.txt");

    char buff;
    int iter;

    if (!input.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    else {
        while (!input.eof()) {
            buff = input.get();
            if (buff == ' ')
                output << ' ';
            if (buff == '\n')
                output << '\n';
            if (buff >= 'A' && buff <= 'Z') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('A');
                iter = (iter - k + 26) % 26;
                iter += (int)'A';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'a' && buff <= 'z') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('a');
                iter = (iter - k + 26) % 26;
                iter += (int)'a';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'А' && buff <= 'Я') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('А');
                iter = (iter - k + 32) % 32;
                iter += (int)'А';
                output << char(iter);
            }
            if (buff >= 'а' && buff <= 'я') {
                iter = int(buff) - int('а');
                iter = (iter - k + 32) % 32;
                iter += (int)'а';
                output << char(iter);
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int k = 0;
    cout << "Сдвиг: ";
    cin >> k;

    if (k < 1)
        return 0;

    cout << "Шифровка Цезарь. " << '\n';
    CaesarIn(k);
    cout << "Дешифровка Цезарь." << '\n';
    CaesarOut(k);

    cout << "Шифровка Моноалфавит. " << '\n';
    MonoAlphabetIn(k);
    cout << "Дешифровка Моноалфавит." << '\n';
    MonoAlphabetOut(k);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Даже заглядывать так далеко не буду - потому что, как, по-вашему, что вы тут проверяете?

```
if (65 >= int(cstr[i]) <= 87) {
```

А на самом деле вы тут написали

```
if (true) {
```

Потому что вы сначала сравниваете

```
65 >= int(cstr[i])
```

а потом результат - `true` или `false`, т.е. 1 или 0, сравниваете с 87 - не превосходит ли оно 87? Нет, не превосходит...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на мою реализацию шифра Цезаря на с может поможет! Вариант передачи ключа шифра через командную строку:
        /*
        Implement a program that encrypts messages using Caesar’s cipher.
        */

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int k;
    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
        if (argc == 2)  //Check that program was run with one command-line argument
        {
            //Iterate over the provided argument to make sure all characters are digits
            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
            { 
                while (!isdigit(argv[1][i])) //if one of characters are digits
                {
                    printf("Usage: ./caesar key1\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            //Convert that command-line argument from a string to an int
            k = atoi(argv[1]);
            //Prompt user for plaintext
            string s = get_string("plaintext: ");

            printf("ciphertext:");
            //Iterate over each character of the plaintext
            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i ++)
            {
                //if character lowercase 
                if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') 
                {
                    //position in ascii
                    int ki = (s[i] + k % 26);
                    //after the shifting to going wrapping around alphabetically
                    if (ki > 'z')
                    {
                        printf("%c", ('a' + ((ki) - 'z') - 1)); //rotate around alphabetically
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%c", ki); //if not alpha
                    }
                }
                //if character uppercase
                else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    int ki = (s[i] + k % 26);
                    //after the shifting to going wrapping around alphabetically
                    if (ki > 'Z')
                    {
                        printf("%c", ('A' + ((ki) - 'Z') - 1)); //rotate around alphabetically
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%c", ki);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", s[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key1\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Когда-то писал Шифр Цезаря, вот код, может поможет:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
// Функция проверяет является ли буква прописной
int isUpper(char letter);

// Функция проверяет является ли буква строчной
int isLower(char letter);

// Функция производит шифровку используя шифр Цезаря
char encryption(char letter, int key);

char disencryption(char letter, int key);

int main()
{
    int c;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char string[10];
    int key;
    printf("Введите строку (без пробелов длинною максимум 50 символов): ");
    gets(string);
    printf("Введите ключ (число сдвигов букв): ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        string[i] = encryption(string[i], key);
    }
    printf("\nШифрованная строка: ");
    puts(string);
    printf("\nЖелаете произвести дешифрование? Нажмите Enter\n");
    c = _getch();
    if(c==13)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        string[i] = disencryption(string[i], key);
    }
    printf("\nДешифрованная строка: ");
    puts(string);
    }
    else
    exit (0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int isUpper(char letter)
{
    int result = 0;
    // Если символ больше либо равна 'А' и меньше либо равна 'Я', то вернуть 1(true)
    if (letter >= 'А' && letter <= 'Я')
        result = 1;

    return result;
}

int isLower(char letter)
{
    int result = 0;
    // Если символ больше либо равен 'а' и меньше либо равна 'я', то вернуть 1(true)
    if (letter >= 'а' && letter <= 'я')
        result = 1;

    return result;  
}

char encryption(char letter, int key)
{
    if (isUpper(letter))
    {
        letter += key;
        if ((int)letter > 90)
        {
            key = letter - 90;
            letter = 65 + key - 1;
        }
    }
    if (isLower(letter))
    {
        letter += key;
        if ((int)letter > 122)
        {
            key = letter - 122;
            letter = 97 + key - 1;
        }
    }
    return letter;
}

char disencryption(char letter, int key)
{
    if (isUpper(letter))
    {
        letter -= key;
        if ((int)letter > 90)
        {
            key = letter + 90;
            letter = 65 - key + 1;
        }
    }
    if (isLower(letter))
    {
        letter -= key;
        if ((int)letter > 122)
        {
            key = letter + 122;
            letter = 97 - key + 1;
        }
    }
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде нет модульной арифметики, зато есть магические константы. И это плохо.